# Fitting a gaussian curve to data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a gaussian curve to some data that I have but I'm not getting the correct fit. The code I currently have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
data = x,y = np.genfromtxt('Co60_600s.csv', unpack=True, delimiter=',',skip_header=0,     usecols=(0,1))


#gaussian function
def gauss(x,A,x0,sigma):
    return A*(np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma)**2))

#Plotting the previous figure with gaussian curve and estimated values

A= 750
x0= 1200
sigma=10
ax1.plot(y,x)

ax1.plot(data,gauss(data, A, x0, sigma), linestyle='-', color='r', label='Estimated Best  Fit')


ax1.set_xlim(0,1400)
ax1.set_ylim(0,2000)
```

with a result of

[image: final graph]

Comment: You could try `xs=np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(),500);ax1.plot(xs, gauss(xs, A, x0, sigma), ...)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you either linked the .csv so we could recreate it. But it looks like the source of your errors is (2*sigma)**2) is wrong. It should be 2*sigma**2. That said (and this is the really important part) numpy and scipy are well tested, highly optimized libraries that are much faster than what you are probably able to write. So use them whenever possilbe